# Endeca cluster setup with Apache load balancing

Tags: endeca

I configured  endeca cluster with Apache load balancing of 2 dgraph.. both dgraph are running  in different  machine... Apache port 5555 used for load balancing...I have two application servers... I'm getting endeca response from only  one dgraph not able to get the response from another dgraph and it give no record....  In which machine 5555 port must be running??? It should run both dgraph machine or web server machine???? Can  you guys  me for getting response from both dgraph....  I need to finish it quickly....

Thanks in advance,

---

thank you...

```
DgraphA1 - running in machine A
DgraphB1 - running in machine B (ITL Host)

App server1 pointing to DgraphA1 and Appserver2 pointing to DgraphB1.


Below things are configured in apache for endeca load balancing.I configured the listen port 5555 in Machine A apache..
For App servers, apache are configured in Machine A httpd.conf file. 


NameVirtualHost *:5555

<VirtualHost *:5555>

ServerName MachineA

ProxyPass / balancer://dgraphs/

ProxyPassReverse / balancer://dgraphs/

<Proxy balancer://dgraphs>

BalancerMember http://MachineA:15000 loadfactor=1 retry=0

BalancerMember http://MachineB:15000 loadfactor=1 retry=0

</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>

<Location /balancer-manager>

SetHandler balancer-manager

</Location>
```

Comment: Can you add your Apache configuration to the post?

Comment: @radimpe thank you apache configuration added

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself.

Apache 5555 port need to Run in ITLHost(DgraphB1)

Both App server need to point the ITL Host(DgraphB1) and Port 5555.

Everything working fine..